# How do I get the Trigger name of parent pipeline inside the child pipeline, without using parameters

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have the following set up in my ADF

Main pipeline -> child pipeline1 -> child pipeline2

‘Trigger_A’ is setup for the Main pipeline. Is there a way to get this trigger name in child pipeline2 WITHOUT using parameters?

In other words, if I do @pipeline().triggerName in child pipeline2, I get a uniquie Id, but I want to get value ‘Trigger_A’.

Please let me know.

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my [research](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables),the `@pipeline().triggerName` can only be used in the scope of specific pipeline.(For you, it's the Main Pipeline)

If you want to refer to the value of trigger name, you need to pass the trigger name as parameter into the sub pipeline.

Another idea(A little trouble): if the trigger name is static,you could write a custom rest api to get the value and use [Web Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) in the sub pipelines.